# removing redundant HTML code from page using jQuery or PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, concrete5

I have some code in my Concrete5 template which i dont need if the user has not uploaded gallery images. I therefore need to remove the following code IF it contains no images:

```
<ul class="Gal_2">
       <li class="Frst">    
       </li>

       <li>
       </li>
</ul>
```

It looks like this when it has images in:

```
<ul class="Gal_2">
    <li class="Frst">
        <p><a rel="group" href="/concrete/files/2113/6352/1788/Lighthouse.jpg"><img width="1024" height="768" alt="Lighthouse.jpg" src="/concrete/files/2113/6352/1788/Lighthouse.jpg"></a>
        </p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p><a rel="group" href="/concrete/concrete/themes/greek_yogurt/Images/TEMP_IMG1.jpg"><img width="800" height="537" alt="Island Rab" src="/concrete/concrete/themes/greek_yogurt/Images/TEMP_IMG1.jpg" style="float: left;"></a>
        </p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

What would be the fastest way to check and remove the markup?

Comment: You should be able to check this on the PHP server side, during the process of generating the HTML page.

Comment: Not really... Because its using a custom block to output the HTML markup. Rather than down-voting? Maybe some help or advice in PHP would be nice!!

Comment: Validate at server side

Comment: @PriceCheaperton: from where your loading images ?

Comment: If you remove the content from the client side (in Javascript) it is completely useless because the network ha already been used to transfer useless data, your browser has already take time to load the DOM including the useless part. And then, you are using javascript time to remove just a little part of the DOM (which your browser does not really care).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using [**:not**](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) and [**:has**](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/)

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ERMuH/)**

```
$('.Gal_2:not(:has(a))').remove();
```

Comment: +1 It works if you change `#Gal_2` to `.Gal_2`.

Comment: Thanks @insertusernamehere, so nice of you.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like the following:

```
<?php if (count($images)):?>
<ul class="Gal_2">
    <?php foreach($images as $index => $image):?>
        <li <?php echo $index == 0 ? 'class="Frst"' : ''?>>
            <p>
                <a rel="group" href="<?php echo $image['path']?>">
                    <img width="1024" height="768" src="<?php echo $image['path']?>">
                </a>
            </p>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach?>
</ul>
<?php endif?>
```

It is better to filter this out on the server side, because the user does not need these empty elements - first they have to be transmitted with the HTTP request and after that they have to be removed with JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to show me this... I think its the best way to learn, by having answers so i can visualise it. Knowledge should be shared.. Thank you again..

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

<s>if (! $('.Gal_2 img').length) {
       $('.Gal_2').remove();
    }</s>

Fixed version for the case there's one **.Gal_2** with images and other without them:

```
$('.Gal_2').each(function() {
   if (! $(this).find('img').length) {
      $(this).remove();
   }
});
```

Comment: This will not remove the gallery elements if there are more than one .Gal_2 lists and one of them has images.

Comment: Thanks for spotting this, I've updated my answer with a fixed version.

Comment: This solution will remove the ones which do have images in them. The OP wanted the opposite.

Comment: Oops, this is not my day, fixed again, thanks for the heads up :-)

Answer (score 0):

You would probably use something like:

```
if (!$('img', 'ul.Gal_2 li')) {
    $('ul.Gal_2 li').hide();
    // or
    $('ul.Gal_2 li').remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

another one

```
if($(".Frst").children().length) ? **do smthng** : $(".Gal_2").remove();
```